# How to implement firebase analytics in android application efficiently?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, android-annotations

Good day, I have been working on an android project for last 3 months. As time passes project grows big, but now I need to implement **Firebase Analytics** into the project, to track every app screen and event as well. But I found out that, using the basic implementation again and again for every `onClick` methods or classes in my project and custom events as well doesn't worth much. I need an efficient/generic way to implement it. Let me know if you can help this me out.

**What I checked already:**

[Firebase Analytic Official doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android/events)
[Implement analytics efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033290/is-this-a-correct-and-efficient-way-to-implement-firebase-analytics)

I also found [this blog](https://medium.com/wantedly-engineering/better-analytics-in-android-with-annotation-processing-and-kotlinpoet-bffca3f24c37) which illustrates to implement it using KotlinPoet (As I'm using Kotlin with MVVM pattern for the development), AnnotationProcessor and EventBus and some other libraries. But I don't found it useful (Cz, just for the analytics I had to work a lot and put those annotations for every classes as well).

So, I want to know the *best practice* and *efficient* way to implement it into my **large** project easily.
Any kind of help will be appreciable. Thanks for your time.

Comment: FYI on Stack Overflow, and many other forums, backtick quotes are used for marking bits of code, not for highlighting text.

Comment: Okay I understand. Help me if you can. Thanks